# PowerBuilder MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0 encoding attribute gone

Tags: xml, encoding, domdocument, powerbuilder

I have a very simple PowerBuilder code:

```
OLEObject lole_DOM
lole_DOM = CREATE OLEObject
lole_DOM.ConnectToNewObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0")
lole_DOM.LoadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root/>')
MessageBox("", String(lole_DOM.XML))
DESTROY lole_DOM
```

And the result I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root/>
```

Where did encoding attribute go? Not sure who to blame, PowerBuilder or MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0, any ideas?

Using PowerBuilder version 11.5.1 Build 5097

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/542040/317266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. As stated in the "Remarks" section of the [documentation for the `xml` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms755989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The `xml` property always returns a Unicode string. That is, the `xml` property for `DOMDocument` converts the document from its original encoding to Unicode. As a result, the original encoding attribute is removed. For example, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` appears in the `xml` property as follows.
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> ```

In constrast, if you save the document into a file with `save()` you will see that the processing instruction is complete in the file, and the file is encoded accordingly.